# Browser interface to command line python program

Tags: python, firefox, sqlite, webkit

I have a command line tool that I have written (in Python) that interfaces to a SQLite database (one DB per user). This program presents a lot of data to the user which can be cumbersome in a terminal.

One option is to provide a wxPython interface, but another thought is to leverage Firefox or Webkit to provide an interface.

Anyone ever go about something like this? Or else any very easy ways to add graphical interfaces to manipulate large amounts of data in python programs? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The django [automatic admin interface](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin) (you can use legacy DBs, and sqlite), or [databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/#ref-contrib-databrowse) application are worth considering as easy, (almost) no-coding web interfaces.

Comment: nice, i didn't know about the databrowse feature.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at Qt's model/view framework. It's trivial to take a SQL result set and map it into a table view etc...

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/sql-tablemodel.html

This works quite well from PyQt4 also.